# Vue.js delegate event handler to parent component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a global component on my `VM`, like this

```
Vue.component('dropdown', function () {
    template: require('./templates/Dropdown.template.html'),

    components: {
        clients: require('./../modal/Clients.js')
    }
});
```

As you can see this global component has its own child component - `clients`

In the template of this child component I have `click` event happening:

```
<button @click.prevent="submitForm"></button>
```

Question:

*Is it possible that the first global component `Dropdown` would be responsible for handling this event?*

So I would have it like this

```
Vue.component('dropdown', function () {

    ...

    methods: {
        submitForm: function () {
            // handling event
        }
    },

    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preferred way to do this would be to send the event upwards using by `$dispatch` This avoids tight coupling which slightly defeats the purpose of independent, reusable components There is a very similar example in the [documentation](http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Custom_Events).

Comment: The VueJS developers removed the `$dispatch` method.

Comment: that's still a valid answer, there is no reason to downvote it. the API has changed, now one should use `$emit()` instead of dispatching the event

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do this in your child component:

**ChildComponent.vue**

```
<button @click="$emit('click')">Child Component Button</button>
```

It will trigger the handler defined in your parent

**ParentComponent.vue**

```
<ChildComponent @click="myHandler()"/>
```